# Unable to increment a variable counter within a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using HTML Canvas and have generated a grid on it using a For loop in JavaScript. On the grid along the top just above each line I would like to display numbers to count them however with the counter variable I created within the loop, across the whole way it only displays  what I initialized it to and does not increment each time the loop runs.

```
for (let topNum = 44; topNum < 1990; topNum = topNum + 50) {
  let x = 45;
  let i = 0;

  c.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  c.font = "30px serif";
  c.fillText(i, topNum, x);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Citizen4/4fd0wmb6/3/

Comment: every time your loop runs, your var is being re-initialised to zero. Declare a var outside the loop (as you've used i before, use another letter, e.g. j, for clarity in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand but the problem is that you should move `let i = 0` outside the for:

```
let i = 0;
for (let numTop = 44; numTop < 1990; numTop = numTop + 50) {
  let x = 45;//Each time it starts again     

  c.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  c.font = "30px serif";
  c.fillText(i, numTop, x);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: I would move `let x = 45;` out of the loop too so it does not get redefined over and over.

Answer (score 2):

Move x=45 and i=0 outside of for loop so they don't get reset every time the function loops.

```
i=0;
x=45;
for loop goes here.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvwL890h/

Answer (score 1):

Remember **scope** and that both `let` and `const` are created and assigned values on the line they are defined.

Also remember that you can change `v = v + 1` to `v++` and `v = v + 50` to `v+=50`

```js
for (let numTop = 44, i = 0, x = 45; numTop < 1990; numTop += 50, i++) {
  c.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  c.font = "30px serif";
  c.fillText(i, numTop, x);
}
```

The code above shows that you can define multiple variables in your `for` loop and you can change values within the `for` loop declaration.

In this case we define `numTop`, `x` and `i` in the `for` loop and we adjust the values of both `numTop` and `i` within the `for` loop.